# What should I use for hosting videos for streaming in my mobile app

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming

I have an app for Android and iOS, and I want to integrate video. However, if I put the video in the app, it will make the app very big. So I want to stream the video from the web. What are some good services I can use to host the videos? They are a total of about 25-30 MB. I would like to use a service with a free plan that I can start out with until I have a lot of users.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at HTTP or RTMP (Real Time Messaging Protocol) streaming via [**Amazon Cloudfront**](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/).  They have cheap $per/GB pricing and support secured and/or authenticated access to resources.